# Knowrob installation: failed to process package 'json_prolog_msgs'

Tags: roscpp, knowrob, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The folowing error occured during installation `KnowRob` according to [this instruction](http://knowrob.org/installation/catkin):

```
CMake Error at /home/al/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/catkin/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "roscpp" with any
  of the following names:

    roscppConfig.cmake
    roscpp-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "roscpp" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "roscpp_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "roscpp"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/al/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/json_prolog_msgs/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/al/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/json_prolog_msgs/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
<== Failed to process package 'json_prolog_msgs': 
  Command '/home/al/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/message_generation/env.sh cmake /home/al/ros_catkin_ws/src/stacks/knowrob/json_prolog_msgs -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/al/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/json_prolog_msgs -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/al/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -G Unix Makefiles' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Instalation `Indigo` from sources according to [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source) on Ubuntu 14.04 was successfull. May be somehow it's related with `rosjava` configuration?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201594/knowrob-installation:-failed-to-process-package-%27json_prolog_msgs%27/) by [Alexey Reshetnyak](https://answers.ros.org/users/21462/alexey-reshetnyak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2015-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just to be sure, 'roscd roscpp' does work for you? And you have sourced all setup.bash-es as needed?

I've had similar issues, though related to messages that catkin thought to be defined twice after I've installed rosjava from source into my workspace. What worked for me was to install rosjava into a separate catkin workspace, i.e. to chain two workspaces as described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying). My layout was thus

```
~/ros/system_pkgs/src/rosjava etc <-- refers to /opt/ros/indigo/...
~/ros/custom_pkgs/src/knowrob etc <-- refers to system_pkgs workspace
```

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2015-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alexey Reshetnyak](https://answers.ros.org/users/21462/alexey-reshetnyak/) on 2015-01-23**:
Thank you! But it solves problem only particularly. After a command `source ~/ros_catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` error with `roscpp` dissapeared. And I got new error about `rosjava`. I posted a [new question](http://answers.ros.org/question/201616/how-to-chain-knowrob-and-rosjava-workspaces/).